# let variable is undefined in useImperativeHandle function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, lottie, react-native-web

I work with the lottie-web package in a .web.js file under React Native (Expo).

My problem is that the let variable anim is undefined in the functions in useImperativeHandle. In the useEffect anim works wonderfully. For example if I access anim.play() right after the initialize at useEffect it works. But at the play() function in imperative it doesn't work.

At my parent component I create a ref with useRef and pass the ref to the component

```
const lottieAnim = useRef(null);
```

--

```
let anim;
useEffect(() => {
  const lottieOptions = {
    container: divContainer.current,
    renderer: 'svg',
    loop,
    autoplay,
    segments: segments !== false,
    animationData,
    rendererSettings,
  };
  anim = lottie.loadAnimation({ ...lottieOptions, ...options });
  // anim.play(); works here 

  if (onAnimationFinish) {
    anim.addEventListener('complete', onAnimationFinish);
  }
}, []);

useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
  stop() {
    anim.stop();
  },
  pause() {
    anim.pause();
  },
  play() {
    anim.play();
    // anim is undefined
  },
  setSpeed(s) {
    anim.setSpeed(s);
  },
  setDirection(d) {
    anim.setDirection(d);
  },
  playSegments(s) {
    anim.playSegments(s);
  },
}));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update 2023

I've created a package for connecting third-party packages to react via useImperativeHandler in an easier way, you might find it useful and easier to use .
[react-aptor](https://github.com/realamirhe/react-aptor)

That is because React has no clue what `anim` is when it creates API functions in useImperativeHandle (duo to closure and react updating strategies that don't trigger any update by mutating a variable). There is some way you can handle this, after all, it comes to personal opinion what to do, I will use something like this which work the best
for me.

### Add GetApi Function

```
// hanlder.js
const stop = anim => anim.stop()
// api.js
const getAPI = anim => () => ({
  stop: stop.bind(this, anim),
  // or simply
  setSpeed: s => anim.setSpeed(s),

  // you can mock APIs here if anim is null or throw an Error
});
```

### store `anim` in a state

> store `anim` in the state for the first render only and use it in the dependencies array of getApi useEffect

```
const [anim, setAnim] = React.useState(null);

React.useEffect(() => {
  // initialization part
}, []);

React.useImperativeHandle(ref, getAPI(anim), [anim]);
```

Comment: Excellent sir. It works, thank you for the detailed description of the problem!